# sudo: (whatever): command not found on RHEL 5.8

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, sudo

Whenever I try to run any command present in /sbin/ with a sudouser such as "sudo ifconfig", I get the error saying sudo: ifconfig: command not found.

I added the path of sbin to PATH

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

It works fine but When I change the terminal or restart, the PATH resets. How can I permanently add path to PATH variable?

And am I missing something else too?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @jaypal: it doesnt help

Comment: @leeduhem: bash shell

Comment: @Pradeep Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Commands executed under `sudo` do not inherit most of your environment, particularly your `$PATH`.

To see what's inherited, try running

```
sudo printenv
```

If you want to execute a command that's not in `sudo`'s default `$PATH`, you'll have to update `$PATH` *in the command itself* or specify the full pathname of the command.

You can also use `-E` to propagate your current environment through `sudo`, but that's not always permitted.

See also `/etc/sudoers`, which can be used to configure the behavior of `sudo`, and `man sudo`.

`sudo -l` will also show useful information, including which commands you're allowed to execute and some (but not all) information about the environment.

Comment: `sudo -l` could be used to list the allowed commands for the invoking user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`, you could append

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

to your `~/.bashrc` to add `/sbin` to your `$PATH` permanently.

---

`sudo -l` could be used to list the allowed commands for the invoking user, it also shows the secure path.

`sudo -l` gives this on my Fedora 19 system:

```
$ sudo -l
    ...
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin
```

and `sudo printenv PATH` gives the same result:

```
$ sudo printenv PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

This `secure_path` is set in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

My `sudo` version:

```
$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.6p7
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.6p7
Sudoers file grammar version 42
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.6p7
```

Comment: I tried appending to ~/.bashrc, but I got a permission denied error

Comment: What is your command and what is the exact error message?

Comment: I tried to view the file as root "cat ~/.bashrc", when I got the permission denied error.
How can I add /sbin permanently to PATH for sudousers
"sudo printenv" - has no /sbin in the PATH

Comment: @Pradeep Looks like your `sudo` is broken. What is your `sudo -l` output?

Comment: @Pradeep Root user will bypass the normal Linux file permissions, so as root, your `cat ~/.bashrc` should not give permission denied error. Does you enable SELinux or something similar in your system?

Comment: Sudo -l output:
 Matching Defaults entries for bhavani on this host:
    !visiblepw, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES
    LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Runas and Command-specific defaults for bhavani:


User bhavani may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

Comment: `cat ~/.bashrc` 
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

Comment: @Pradeep Can you find the assignment to `secure_path` in your `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: No, there is no entry of secure_path in /etc/sudousers

Comment: @Pradeep Maybe you need to upgrade your `sudo`, or change the configure of it. Please refer to my updated answer.